# associative array does not save mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

tournament.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TournamentPlayer = require('../models/tournamentPlayer');
var SportPlayer = require('../models/sportPlayer');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TournamentSchema = new Schema({
    tournamentPlayers:[{
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        ref: 'TournamentPlayer' 
    }],
    buyin: Number,
    entrants: Number,
    prizePool: Number,
    name: String,
    sport: String,
    endOfRegistration:Date,
    sportsPlayers:[{
        type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
        ref: 'SportPlayer' 
    }],
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tournament', TournamentSchema);
```

api.js

```
tournament.tournamentPlayers[player.userId]=player;
console.log("ass array"+util.inspect(tournament.tournamentPlayers,false,null));
console.log("ass array element" + util.inspect(tournament.tournamentPlayers[player.userId] ,false,null));
console.log("ass array just in case"+util.inspect(tournament.tournamentPlayers,false,null));
tournament.tournamentPlayers.push(player);
console.log("push"+util.inspect(tournament.tournamentPlayers,false,null));
```

Output

```
ass array[]
ass array element{ username: 'batman',
  roster: 
   { __v: 0,
 userId: '57bb89eb10c4b4ac124980b9',
 tournamentId: '57d49f5169cc78ac21c5e791',
 _id: '57d4b421315f1b501ad5456f',
 playerRoster: 
  [ { _id: '57cfe922dcba0f295f57e26d', playerFirstName: 'Julio' },
    { _id: '57cfe939dcba0f295f57e274', playerFirstName: 'Odell' } ] },
  rank: 'blah',
  totalPoints: 0,
  userId: '57bb89eb10c4b4ac124980b9',
  _id: '57d4b421315f1b501ad54570' }
ass array just in case[]
push[{"username":"batman","roster":{"__v":0,"userId":"57bb89eb10c4b4ac124980b9","tournamentId":"57d49f5169cc78ac21c5e791","_id":"57d4b421315f1b501ad5456f","playerRoster":[{"_id":"57cfe922dcba0f295f57e26d","playerFirstName":"Julio"},{"_id":"57cfe939dcba0f295f57e274","playerFirstName":"Odell"}]},"rank":"blah","totalPoints":0,"userId":"57bb89eb10c4b4ac124980b9","_id":"57d4b421315f1b501ad54570"}]
```

I am trying to declare and add objects to an associative array. When I look them up, I want to use userId instead of _id. When trying with this code, the object can be called directly tournamentPlayers[userId], but doesn't display as part of the array tournamentPlayers. When I do a regular push, it displays, but this isn't what I want. I am able to use the object, but can't save it through mongoose.

I've seen a couple of questions but they did not answer this. The second answer here has strict: false as a setting, but not for a single schema element.
[Mongoose: Saving as associative array of subdocuments vs array of subdocuments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832950/mongoose-saving-as-associative-array-of-subdocuments-vs-array-of-subdocuments/18860010#18860010)

How can I declare and add objects to an associative array in mongoose?

Comment: associative array

Comment: Ok. 2) What's the rest of `tournament.js`?

Comment: Ok It is added.